# 404 on site pages when using https

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, certbot

I set up a backend API on EC2 and then followed the docs from certbot to enable https.  According to the docs I ran "sudo certbot --nginx" which is supposed to update the nginx file directly to enable ssl.  However, when I go to https:///admin/ I get a 404 error.  If I use HTTP instead everything is fine.  Here is my nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Do I need to change something here or might the issue be elsewhere?  This is a Django backend if that helps and I am using nginx and gunicorn on the Ubuntu EC2 instance

Comment: you're running django server using `python manage.py runserver` and using nginx you're trying to make the site https, right?

Comment: I believe that's correct.  I'm not running python manage.py runserver inside of the Ubuntu server for production but when setting up the project was yes.  Nginx is being used to run the project inside of the EC2 server and is working with HTTP but not recognizing the SSL cert or something at the moment.